# GeoIP in localhost

Tags: node.js, geoip

I am using GeoIP to get country from client address but it returns `null`

```
 ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
 country = geoip.lookup(ip).country;
```

I think this is because I am using localhost since the detected ip is 127.0.1.
How to solve that?

Comment: so what happens if you don't use localhost? if your server is publicly accessible, I'll click and link and let you know what it says for me.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe it worked for me on http://gentle-plains-8744.herokuapp.com/ with the same method

Comment: when you get a local loopback for the forwarded-for header then go back up the chain until you have a public on

Comment: @ratchetfreak i am sorry for being stupid but i didnt understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use services like http://fugal.net/ip.cgi or http://ifconfig.me/ip to get your external IP address via `http.get()` or run a shell command using `child_process.exec()` (like `$ ip` on OS X), but it's not a cross-platform solution. I don't think it's possible to get local machine external IP using `http.IncomingMessage` object (`req`) or `os.networkInterfaces()` method.

In your case, I would default to some country/latitude/whatever you need in case of `null` from `geoip.lookup()`, at least in development environment.

```
var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
var country = geo ? geo.country : 'US';
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I will do but I will have to wait production to test whether it works or not :(